# For linux (nixos) xserver using a macbookpro, what can I do to prevent movement of mouse while clicking

Tags: mouse, macintosh, x-server, nixos

I have NixOs installed in my macbook pro. My problem is that the mouse is too sensitive. When I click, the mouse moves slightly, causing the click to happen at a different place. I observe that it never happens in either OSX in the same machine, or in other Linux desktops other than in MBookPro. So 1) what can I do (or what setting should I change in `xorg.conf`) to avoid this happening? 2) Can it be done by a setting in `nixos/configuration.nix` ?